# Qml and C++ interaction: return by pointer or by copy

Tags: c++, qt, qml

So I have a Q_PROPERTY exposed to qml like below

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantMap info READ getInfo NOTIFY infoChanged)

QVariantMap ProfileInfo::getInfo()
{
    return info;
}
```

Now, my question is would the approach below would be more efficient and less costly?

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantMap* info READ getInfo NOTIFY infoChanged)

QVariantMap* ProfileInfo::getInfo()
{
    return &info;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *slightly* more efficient (QVariantMap uses [implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), so a copy is not expensive), but your biggest problem is that QML doesn't know how to deal with a `QVariantMap *`, only with a `QVariantMap` (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object)).